# best way to perform one-hot encoding and explode column with prefix pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Trying to replicate pandas code in pyspark 2.x.

say I have dataframe as follows:

```
    age      education    country
0   22          A          Canada
1   34          B          Mongolia
2   55          A          Peru
3   44          C          Korea
```

Usually in pandas I would scale numerical columns and one hot encode categorical and get:

```
    age      education_A education_B education_C    country_Canada   country_Mongolia ...
0   0            1           0           0                1                 0 
1   0.3          0           1           0                0                 0
2   1            1           0           0                0                 0         ...
3   0.7          0           0           1                ...              ...
```

In pyspark I've done

```
str_indexer1 = StringIndexer(inputCol="education", outputCol=education+"_si", handleInvalid="skip")
str_indexer2 = StringIndexer(inputCol="country", outputCol=country+"_si", handleInvalid="skip")
mod_df = str_indexer1.fit(df).transform(df)
mod_df = str_indexer2.fit(df).transform(mod_df)

ohe1 = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="education", outputCol=education+"_ohe")
ohe2 = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="country", outputCol=country+"_ohe")

ohe1.fit(mod_df).transform(mod_df)
```

This gives me

```
    age      education   country          education_si    country_si     education_ohe
0   0            A         Canada              1              1           (1,0,0,0)
1   0.3          B         Mongolia            2              2           (0,1,0,0)
2   1            A         Peru                1              3           (1,0,0,0)
3   0.7          C         Korea               3              4           (0,0,1,0)
```

From here I cannot find out how to explode education_ohe into education_A, etc...

How can I do this and also is more efficient way to perform ohe and scaler in large dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in `oneHotEncoder` in pyspark's functions, but I could not get it to provide true one-hot encoded columns.

That being said the following code will get the desired result.

Using the following dataframe.

```
df.show()
+---+---------+--------+
|age|education| country|
+---+---------+--------+
| 22|        A|  Canada|
| 34|        B|Mongolia|
| 55|        A|    Peru|
| 44|        C|   Korea|
+---+---------+--------+
```

You can select all the distinct column values, and iteratively create additional columns.

```
variables_dict = {}

for col in df.columns:
    variables_dict[col] = [row[col] for row in df.distinct().collect()]

for col in variables_dict.keys():
    for val in variables_dict[col]:
        df = df.withColumn("{}_{}".format(col, val), functions.when((df[col] == val), 1).otherwise(0))

df.show()
+---+---------+--------+------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------------+
|age|education| country|age_22|age_44|age_55|age_34|education_A|education_C|education_B|country_Canada|country_Korea|country_Peru|country_Mongolia|
+---+---------+--------+------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------------+
| 22|        A|  Canada|     1|     0|     0|     0|          1|          0|          0|             1|            0|           0|               0|
| 34|        B|Mongolia|     0|     0|     0|     1|          0|          0|          1|             0|            0|           0|               1|
| 55|        A|    Peru|     0|     0|     1|     0|          1|          0|          0|             0|            0|           1|               0|
| 44|        C|   Korea|     0|     1|     0|     0|          0|          1|          0|             0|            1|           0|               0|
+---+---------+--------+------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------------+
```

You can then use the same `variables_dict` to apply the one_hot_encoder to another dataframe.

```
df2.show()
+---+---------+--------+
|age|education| country|
+---+---------+--------+
| 22|        A|  Canada|
| 66|        B|Mongolia|
| 55|        D|    Peru|
| 44|        C|   China|
+---+---------+--------+
```

The dataframe above has column variables that have been seen before ie. (66, D, China).

We can use the following code to transform 'df2' to have identical columns as 'df'.

```
for col in variables_dict.keys():
    for val in variables_dict[col]:
        df2 = df2.withColumn("{}_{}".format(col, val), functions.when((df2[col] == val), 1).otherwise(0))

+---+---------+--------+------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------------+
|age|education| country|age_22|age_44|age_55|age_34|education_A|education_C|education_B|country_Canada|country_Korea|country_Peru|country_Mongolia|
+---+---------+--------+------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------------+
| 22|        A|  Canada|     1|     0|     0|     0|          1|          0|          0|             1|            0|           0|               0|
| 66|        B|Mongolia|     0|     0|     0|     0|          0|          0|          1|             0|            0|           0|               1|
| 55|        D|    Peru|     0|     0|     1|     0|          0|          0|          0|             0|            0|           1|               0|
| 44|        C|   China|     0|     1|     0|     0|          0|          1|          0|             0|            0|           0|               0|
+---+---------+--------+------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: you can get the labels from stringindexer directly instead of running distinct().collect()